# Is taking backups pointless after a specifc size is reached?

Tags: backup, restore

I wonder if it makes any sense to make backups after the database has reached a specific size. Today a non failover protected server which stored an internal database of around 100GB crashed at my school, and it took more than 7 hours to restore it from the backup.

So I was puzzled... If it takes around 7 hours to restore a relatively small database does it make any sense to create backups from a specific size onwards?

Imagine very huge databases (like probably Google, Microsoft etc. have) with maybe petabytes of size. If such a database crashes for any reason it's of course nice to have a backup, but it should take weeks if not months to restore it - doesn't that make the backup useless?

Shouldn't you just spare backups in such cases and "simply" put all available resources into failover hardware and so on?

Comment: If the data is important enough to store, then it is certainly important enough to back it up, period... regardless of the database size. Hardware redundancy and fail-over is nice and all, but that protects against certain kinds of failures (e.g. physical corruption)... it should never replace a DB level backup, which protects against logical corruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try my best to address the points you raised here.  Please let us know if you have any questions.

1 - 7 hours for 100GB is far too long.  What are the actual steps in that 7 hour timeframe?  I would think that it includes pulling the backup from tape.  One thing that I do is try and keep the most recent backup on local disk just so I can skip tape recovery in this kind of emergency.  You might also have slow hardware.  One thing that can speed up backups is sending them to multiple files.  I've found good performance gains to be had with ~10 files with 100 GB databases.

2 - Larger databases typically reside on higher editions of database engines, which let you do lots of different types of backups and restores.  You can backup and restore partitions instead of the entire database and the large peta-scale databases you mention are typically distributed across lots of hardware.

3 - Whether a restore takes too long is completely dependent on your SLA.  Depending on the type of outage your Recovery Time Objective and Recovery Point Objectives are going to be different.  Restoring a single database shoudl be a relatively short affair, but having to rebuild an entire server or datacenter is a different kettle of fish.

But backups serve other purposes as well, allowing point in time recovery, page repair for corrupted data, which can happen even in clusters and availability groups and are generally just a good idea.  But if your business demands higher SLA, then it is going to cost hardware.  But you should be able to get a better/faster backup/restore time (in this instance) cheaper than moving up to a highly available cluster hardware and software licensing costs, environment complexity, and more increase that cost.

Answer (score 2):

If your data has to be there for your business to exist, then yes, those backups are kind of important.

If I have a 100 GB in my sales and inventory system (including in-process and scheduled orders) then losing that data means you've lost customer goodwill. You've also got legal issues, since you need to either recreate or refund orders with no data on those orders, or face credit card / bank fraud charges/accusations. Or if I have 100 GB of student records in a public school, then I have a *legal mandate* to maintain copies of those records. I could face lawsuits for losing them.

In other words, [losing the data can mean the end](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=database%20crash%20destroys%20company) of a business.

Remember, a 7 hour downtime window may have been more than a restore. It may have included

- trying to troubleshoot the crash event
- contacting the database vendor's tech support to troubleshoot whatever crashed
- waiting on hardware replacement parts to arrive via courier
- rebuilding a RAID disk array
- building a new server or virtual server
- running the restore
- validating that the restore completed
- running a fresh backup AFTER the restore, to create a new baseline
- etc.

So yes, 7 hour downtime is a long window. But there may be more to it than just doing the restore, I guess is my point.

Also, it is possible the database administrator(s) didn't have a solid database recovery plan in place. Or that they didn't have well-defined [RPO and RTO](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/).

> **RPO: Recovery Point Objective** (RPO) measures how much data you’d lose if your server went down and you brought up the secondary server.  It’s measured in time, not megabytes.  The less time you have, the more frequently you have to get the data to a secondary location.
>
> **RTO: Recovery Time Objective** is how much time you’ve got to get your server’s act together.  Some companies measure it from the time you learn about the problem, some measure when the service is first unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

So the other answers are absolutely correct: *yes, you need a backup plan for your business-critical data, no matter how much you have*.

To think about it another way: *isn't a 7-hour restore better than losing the system altogether?*

But there is a seed of truth in your question: **managing very large databases can be a very difficult problem**.

Backups and restores can take a *very* long time on very big databases, but DBAs have tools we can deploy to help (always depending on budget):

- **Buy faster servers, faster storage, and faster network hardware** to make large backups and restores more manageable. Companies never like spending money, until they calculate how much they'd lose if their data was gone.
- **Invest in good software tools** and learn how to use/configure them. Good compressed backups can increase backup/restore time by a factor of 2x to 10x uncompressed backups.
- Plan and utilize **full vs differential vs tran log backups** to only back up recent changes. This helps your nightly backup time, but won't shorten a restore.
- **Split the database into smaller pieces** that can be backed up separately.  This normally has to be planned for in the application designed.

Lot of other ideas that help in different ways, but depend on the database platform (MS SQL "always-on" mirroring, for example) or depend on the storage vendor (SAN snapshots, for example).